# WebApi 2.2 Automatic Help files broken when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the automated help files and when I build and debug locally they work fine.
When I do a publish to a remote IIS server, instead of the working full api documentation, I get this:

```
Introduction
Provide a general description of your APIs here.

GETPOSTPOSTPOSTDELETEGETGETPOSTGETGETGETGETGETPOSTDELETEPOSTDELETEGETGETPOSTDELETEGETGETGETPOSTGETGETGETGETGETGETPOSTDELETEGETGET
```

When I started the project, the remote deployed help files worked fine, and I have no idea how they broke.  Any tips on where to look would be really appreciated.

Note: The rest of the webservice works exactly the same, all of the api calls work locally and deployed.  it's only the help that is broken.